# Run python app (with tkinter) on raspberry lxde startup (New Terminal)

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, startup, raspbian

i'm trying to run a python app when lxde starts on a raspberry pi.

I'm editing this file  /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
with this line @lxterminal -e ‘cd /home/pi/app/ && python myapp.py’

But it does not start, the terminal appears but with anything on screen.

I use the cd command because i load files from that folder with the script.

Thanks you!